# Constructing rel {0,1} homotopies

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I was told to do this exercise:

> Given paths $\alpha, \beta :I \rightarrow G$ and $e$ the constant closed path given by $e: I \rightarrow G; t \mapsto 1$, construct the rel {0,1} homotopy
> $$m(\alpha) : \alpha \bullet e \simeq \alpha : [0,1] \rightarrow G$$
> where $\bullet$ denotes the concatenation path.

Now, the answer turns out to be:
$$m(\alpha)(s,t) =
\begin{cases}
 \alpha(\frac{2s}{1+t},t)&\text{if}\, 0\leq s \leq \frac{1+t}{2}, 0\leq t\leq1\\
 1&\text{if}\, \frac{1+t}{2}\leq s \leq 1, 0\leq t\leq1\\
\end{cases}$$

There is a few points about this construction that are confusing to me:

1. How was this constructed?
2. $\alpha(t)$ seems two require two inputs rather than one, which I don't get because the domain of  $\alpha(t)$ is the unit interval so it should only require one input variable.

Comment: What is the purpose of $\beta$?

Comment: @PaulFrost ah sorry, $\beta$ is just another path. It is not relevant for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should clarify what $1 \in G$ is. I guess $G$ is a topological space and $1$ is a fixed basepoint. Or do you mean a toplogical group with neutral element $1$? If that should be the case, then it is just a special case of the general topological case.

The definition of the homotopy is in fact *wrong*. We have to replace $\alpha(\frac{2s}{1+t},t)$ by $\alpha(\frac{2s}{1+t})$. The idea behind this definition is simple: At time $t$ divide $[0,1]$ into the subintervals $I_1(t) = [0,\frac{1+t}{2}]$ and $I_2(t) = [\frac{1+t}{2},1]$. On $I_1(t)$ take $\alpha$ and on $I_2(t)$ take $e$. For $t = 0$ we have $I_1(0) = [0,\frac{1}{2}], I_2(0)  = [\frac{1}{2},1]$ and $m(\alpha(s,0) = (\alpha \bullet e)(s)$. For $t = 1$ we have $I_1(1) = [0,1], I_2(1)  = [1,1]$ and $m(\alpha(s,1) = \alpha(s)$.